# My analog clock handles java script not working even though I have no error

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was working on web design which contains dark colour UI analog clock. I made the clock using HTML and CSS. i included script inside HTML, but it is not working. Here is the code of that.This i tried running locally but no use.am new to web designing so i don't know what mistakes i have made.

script part of the html has the problem.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #091921;
}

.clock {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: url(../images/_clock.png);
    background-size: cover;
    border: 4px solid #091921;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 -15px +15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05),
        inset 0 -15px +15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05),
        0 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05),
        inset 0 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.clock:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 10000;
}

.clock .hour,
.clock .min,
.clock .sec {
    position: absolute;
}

.clock .hour,
.hr {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
}

.clock .min,
.mn {
    width: 190px;
    height: 190px;
}

.clock .sec,
.sc {
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
}

.hr,
.mn,
.sc {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /*align-items: center;*/
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.hr:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 8px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #ff105e;
    z-index: 10;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

.mn:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 4px;
    height: 90px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 11;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}
.sc:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 2px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 12;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Javascript Clack UI Dark</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="clock">
        <div class="hour">
            <div class="hr" id="hr"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="min">
            <div class="mn" id="mn"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sec">
            <div class="sc" id="sc"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const deg = 6;
        const hr = document.querySelector('#hr');
        const mn = document.querySelector('#mn');
        const sc = document.querySelector('#sc');

        let day = new Date();
        let hh = day.getHours() * 30;
        let mm = day.getMinutes * deg;
        let ss = day.getSeconds * deg;

        hr.style.transform = `rotateZ(${(hh)+(mm/12)}deg)`;
        mn.style.transform = `rotateZ(${mm}deg)`;
        sc.style.transform = `rotateZ(${ss}deg)`;
    </script>


</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code is running before the document is ready.
I added the code `$(document).ready(function())`.
Full code is like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        const deg = 6;
        const hr = document.querySelector('#hr');
        const mn = document.querySelector('#mn');
        const sc = document.querySelector('#sc');

        let day = new Date();
        let hh = day.getHours() * 30;
        let mm = day.getMinutes * deg;
        let ss = day.getSeconds * deg;

        hr.style.transform = `rotateZ(${(hh)+(mm/12)}deg)`;
        mn.style.transform = `rotateZ(${mm}deg)`;
        sc.style.transform = `rotateZ(${ss}deg)`;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to call your methods. It should be:

```js
let day = new Date();
let hh = day.getHours() * 30;
let mm = day.getMinutes() * deg;  /* added '()' */
let ss = day.getSeconds() * deg;  /* added '()' */
```

Here's your snippet:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #091921;
}

.clock {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: url(../images/_clock.png);
    background-size: cover;
    border: 4px solid #091921;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 -15px +15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05),
        inset 0 -15px +15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05),
        0 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05),
        inset 0 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.clock:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 10000;
}

.clock .hour,
.clock .min,
.clock .sec {
    position: absolute;
}

.clock .hour,
.hr {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
}

.clock .min,
.mn {
    width: 190px;
    height: 190px;
}

.clock .sec,
.sc {
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
}

.hr,
.mn,
.sc {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /*align-items: center;*/
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.hr:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 8px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #ff105e;
    z-index: 10;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

.mn:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 4px;
    height: 90px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 11;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}
.sc:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 2px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 12;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Javascript Clack UI Dark</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="clock">
        <div class="hour">
            <div class="hr" id="hr"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="min">
            <div class="mn" id="mn"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sec">
            <div class="sc" id="sc"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const deg = 6;
        const hr = document.querySelector('#hr');
        const mn = document.querySelector('#mn');
        const sc = document.querySelector('#sc');

        let day = new Date();
        let hh = day.getHours() * 30;
        let mm = day.getMinutes() * deg;
        let ss = day.getSeconds() * deg;
                
        hr.style.transform = `rotateZ(${(hh)+(mm/12)}deg)`;
        mn.style.transform = `rotateZ(${mm}deg)`;
        sc.style.transform = `rotateZ(${ss}deg)`;
    </script>


</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
let hh = day.getHours() * 30;
let mm = day.getMinutes() * deg;
let ss = day.getSeconds() * deg;
```